# How to maintain Session for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my Iphone App, User logins with Username and password. At after user logged in, He can access every attribute, features through APIs. But i want to maintain a session. That is, If user doing nothing in app, After getting 30 mins, Session should expire and user must be asked to login with his Username and password.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on something exactly the same.

I do the following scenario for the session validity:

1. By the first incoming request if the `Session Token` appeared to be invalid I try to re-generate the session key again silently in the background.
2. If procedure #1 did not work for some reasons such as the user changed his password from somewhere else I redirect the user to the log in page again and I alert something like "Your session key has been expired please log in again".

To get more into this I store the Session key in the `NSUserDefaults`:

```
 // Saving the Key
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"ABCDEFGHIJK" forKey:@"SessionKey"];

 // Reading the Key
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SessionKey"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank U Chandan Shetty and Ahmed Kayyali, I will try this.. thank u.

Comment: @Raja: any luck regarding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set previous time `mPreviousTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];` on login and appropriate kThresholdHideValue(In seconds) in your case it is 30min(30*60) and you can check whether the time elapsed using below method...

```
NSTimeInterval timeNow = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
if( ( mPreviousTime + kThresholdHideValue <= timeNow ) )
{
         //Log out
}
```

And also call  `mPreviousTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];` when user performs some action. so you can log out only if user does not perform any action for 30min.