# Maintain Session State in IPhone Application

Tags: iphone, session, background-process

HI, I want to maintain the session in my iphone application. If the application enter in to background state or application is not active i have to move the user to loging screen. How to do this one?

I saw this example but it is not help me to resolve the issue:

[How to maintain Session for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457029/how-to-maintain-session-for-iphone)

Comment: Did my answer helped ? you accepted and again removed from accepted any specific reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow similar concept. When user logging in put some thing as NSUserDefaults like

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"ABCDEFGHIJK" forKey:@"SessionKey"];`

and in application delegate there is one method called

`(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

which will be called when application is going in background. Just remove that set variable for the sessionkey. And while application is again being launched just check the condition and redirect user to desired screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your sharing whenever the application enters in to background i need to check the time of session of inactive not from the login time. If i use the NSTimer inside the applicationDidEnterBackground will work?

Comment: You can do it like add an application start time at the applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoption. Take it as date1 as current date/time. And than you can calculate time between starting of application and going in background. Take other date2 with current date/time It can be done using timeIntervalSinceDate method of NSDate class. Just go through documentation you will have your goal working as you wish. Good Luck. If it works for you Please mark this question as done. Thanks.